# How to specify base date in dateparser library python?

Tags: python, datetime, date-parsing

I was using dateparser to parse date in various patterns.

1) Apr 22, 2011

2) 8. März 2018

3) 5 hours ago

It was working very fine, but the issue came when I ran the same script on the same data on other day because in the pattern like this '5 hours ago', it takes today's date as the base date.

So I even went through the source code of dateparser, checked the docs but didn't found any substantial thing to go forward.

Can someone suggest how can we specify the base date in dateparser?

Also please suggest me if there any other library better then dateparse to tackle this problem.

Code :-

```
res['snippet'] = '''Apr 22, 2011 ... Ingen Technologies Inc.'s (OTC:IGNT) former CEO'''
        date = res['snippet'].split('...')[0].strip()
        try:
            datee = dateparser.parse(date)
            if not datee > datetime.datetime.now():
                dataDict['date'] = datee.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
            else:
                continue
        except:
            continue
```

Comment: you can try http://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/, but I think you may end up  redisgning the result to timedelta from current date. also please post the code you tryied, it help answering the question greatly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> from dateparser import parse
>>> import datetime
>>> parse(u'5 hours ago', settings={'RELATIVE_BASE': datetime.datetime(2011, 4, 22, 4)})
datetime.datetime(2011, 4, 21, 23, 0)
```

The dateparser documentation has a section about a `settings` dict that has a key `RELATIVE_BASE` which is what you are asking (https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/v0.7.0/#settings)